# Deserialization of json using jackson in scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I am trying to de-serialize the below json string to scala object using jackson json api

> {     "Domain1": {        "data-file": "dataFile1",       "filter": {
> "affected-object": "AffectedObject1",           "affected-nd":
> "AffectedNd1"         }   },  "Domain2": {        "data-file": "dataFile2",
> "filter": {             "affected-ci": "AffectedCI2",           "affected-net":
> "AffectedNet2"        }   } }

I tried to use case class and tried first using "ClassOf" in ValueType of "readValue" Method but the output is Map of Map Object. Data is not converted into Case Class Object.

```
case class CrossDomainFilterObj(@JsonProperty("data-file")dataFile: String, 
@JsonProperty("filter")filter: Map[String,String])

val jsonString = "{\"Domain1\": {\"data-file\": \"dataFile1\", \"filter\": { \"affected-object\":
\"AffectedObject1\", \"affected-nd\" : \"AffectedNd1\"}},\"Domain2\": {\"data-file\": 
\"dataFile2\", \"filter\": { \"affected-ci\":\"AffectedCI2\", \"affected-net\" : 
\"AffectedNet2\"}}}"

val mapper = new ObjectMapper
mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
val data = mapper.readValue(jsonString, classOf[Map[String, CrossDomainFilterObj]])
println(data)
```

I am getting output like below

```
Map(Domain1 -> Map(data-file -> dataFile1, filter -> Map(affected-object ->
AffectedObject1, affected-nd -> AffectedNd1)), Domain2 -> Map(data-file -> 
dataFile2, filter -> Map(affected-ci -> AffectedCI2, 
affected-net -> AffectedNet2)))
```

But I am expecting an output like below

```
Map(Domain1 -> CrossDomainFilterObj(dataFile1, Map(affected-object -> 
AffectedObject1, affected-nd -> AffectedNd1)), Domain2 -> 
CrossDomainFilterObj(dataFile2, Map(affected-ci -> 
AffectedCI2, affected-net -> AffectedNet2)))
```

Then i tried using TypeReference as ValueType as shown below,

```
case class CrossDomainFilterObj(@JsonProperty("data-file")dataFile: String, 
@JsonProperty("filter")filter: Map[String,String])

val jsonString = "{\"Domain1\": {\"data-file\": \"dataFile1\", \"filter\": { \"affected-object\":
\"AffectedObject1\", \"affected-nd\" : \"AffectedNd1\"}},\"Domain2\": {\"data-file\": 
\"dataFile2\", \"filter\": { \"affected-ci\":\"AffectedCI2\", \"affected-net\" : 
\"AffectedNet2\"}}}"

val mapper = new ObjectMapper
mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)

val reference = new TypeReference[Map[String, CrossDomainFilterObj]] {}
val data = mapper.readValue(jsonString, reference)
println(data)
```

I am getting error like below

```
dead code following this construct 

"val data = mapper.readValue(jsonString, reference)"
```

Could someone help to identify what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: I would recommend using a **Scala** library instead of a **Java** one. There are many of option, **circe**, **play-json**, **uplicke**, **jsonitter-scala**, etc.

Comment: Yes if it is widely used and supported Scala library will work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure you use `ScalaObjectMapper`:

```
val mapper = new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper
```

Then this should work:

```
val data = mapper.readValue[Map[String, CrossDomainFilterObj]](jsonString)
```

Comment: I am getting error like "Can not find a Value deserializer for abstract type" when I tried the above code

Comment: @Mohan I dunno, [works for me](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/M7Lg9VEzQAWu3ZOeq792xA)